# How to move file from one server to another?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, fpdf

I am trying to move my file from one server to other, i am using the FTP Functions . I tried as follows :-

```
$path = $file['file'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($ext == 'pdf') {
  $pdf->Output($usrname.'TripHub.pdf','F');
  $file = '/mnt/target06/844844/847596/dev.server.com/web/content/'.$usrname.'TripHub.pdf';
  $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
  $ftp_server = "ftp.server.com";  //address of ftp server (leave out ftp://)
  $ftp_user_name = "xxxxx"; // Username
  $ftp_user_pass = "xxxxx";   // Password
  $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);        // set up basic connection
  // login with username and password, or give invalid user message
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass) or die("<h1>You do not have access to this ftp server!</h1>");
  // try to upload $file
   ftp_chdir($conn_id, "hub.server.com/web/content/wp-content/uploads/edd/".date("Y")."/".date("m"));
   //echo "Current directory: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
  if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII) ) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n";
  } else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
  }
  exit;
}
```

Comment: You should not share your password

Comment: thanks ankita, it was put accidently

Comment: Yeah, well its in the edit history forever, so the very 1st thing you need to do is change your passwords on the server, and anywhere else you used the same details

Comment: Once you have done that, then you need to explain your question better - whats not working, what errors do you get etc

Comment: Have you tried using actual path of that PDF file ?

Comment: Oh, and you also need to change your database passwords if you are using a database, as they could be accessed by anyone who downloaded your source code. Ditto any other sensitive information such as api keys etc contained in your source code

Answer (score 0):

```
// open some file for reading
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to upload $file
if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection and the file handler
ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($fp);
```